# ML.Net "No valid instances encountered during data loading" error while loading data file

Tags: machine-learning, ml.net

[error screen shot](https://i.hizliresim.com/kM2Qg9.png)

```
var testDataPath = "model.csv";
IDataView trainingDataView = mlContext.Data.LoadFromTextFile<MovieRating>(trainingDataPath, hasHeader: true, separatorChar: ',');
ITransformer model = trainerEstimator.Fit(trainingDataView);
```

while returning the transformer i have an error like

> No valid instances encountered during data loading

How can i solve it? Any ideas?

Comment: Do you happen to have any quotes in your dataset? If so, try to remove all of them and see if that helps.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: I am currently experiencing this exact issue. Would love to know how to fix it. I do not have any quotes in dataset.

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing this, and solved reviewing my dataset (do they fit into `MovieRating`).

In my case I was missing the `separatorChar: ','` when loading the data view. After including it, the exception was not thrown.